# Worksheet_Calculate to hide command button

Tags: excel, vba

I found the code below for `Worksheet_Change`. But my H29 is formula `=SUM`.
How do I change this to `Worksheet_Calculate` so that the below macro will run?

Basically what I want is if H29 is calculated as being equal to 20, show the button, else hide it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Target = Range("H29") Then
If Target.Value = "20" Then
Me.CommandButton1.Visible = True


Else

Me.CommandButton1.Visible = False

End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the button type, the code to instruct the button will be different. Try this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
'ActiveX button
If Range("H29").Value = 20 Then
  Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton2.Visible = False
Else
  Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton2.Visible = True
End If

'Forms Button
If Range("H29").Value = 20 Then
  Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("CommandButton1").Visible = msoFalse
Else
  Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("CommandButton1").Visible = msoTrue
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I will review it too. I manage to solve it with yourhelp

Answer (score 0):

Sorry asked too soon. Resolved

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
'ActiveX button
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If Range("H29").Value = 20 Then
  Me.CommandButton1.Visible = True
Else
   Me.CommandButton1.Visible = False
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI - it becomes a simple one-liner if you use something like `Me.CommandButton1.Visible = Range("H29").Value = 20`.